# Strange behavior x tick label style versus y tick label style

Tags: pgfplots, sticky-labels

I've made a graph with this code:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
major grid style=black,
axis lines=center,
ymin=0, ymax=0.202,
xmin=0, xmax=5.1,
xtick={0,1,...,5.1},
width=\linewidth,
height=10cm,
xlabel={$F_z(N)$},
ylabel={$\Delta l(m)$},
x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=1, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill},
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=3, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill},
every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.north west)}, anchor=south},
minor xtick={0,0.1,...,5},
minor ytick={0,0.002,...,0.2},
grid=both,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
major grid style=black,
axis lines=center,
ymin=0,
ymax=25,
xmin=0, xmax=0.07,
x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed, /pgf/number format/precision=2, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill},
ytick={0,5,...,25},
tick label style={font=\small},
width=\linewidth,
height=9cm,
xlabel={\small $m$ (kg)},
ylabel={\small $Q$ (kJ)},
%ticks=both,
%minor xtick={0,5,...,40},
minor ytick={0,1,...,25},
grid=both,
ylabel near ticks,
xlabel near ticks,
]
\addplot[very thick, domain=0:1, no markers,samples=3] {250*x}; 
\addplot[color = black, fill  = black, mark  = *,  only marks] coordinates{(0.005,3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The first graph has correct ticks, but then I want to repeat that for my second graph on the x-axe, but it gives me a .10^-2 and I don't want this notation. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question, but does adding `scaled ticks=false` to the second axis environment solve your problem?

Comment: @StefanPinnow YES, thanks, it works. But I still don't understand why I have to do this in the second graph and not in the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong. This is the expected output of your code. If you don't want the ticks to be scaled, either turn it of by adding `scaled ticks=false` to the second graph or in the preamble, or change the range, in which the numbers should be scaled by changing the values of the keys `scale ticks below exponent` and/or `scale ticks above exponent`.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        scaled ticks=false,             % <-- turn scaling off
%        % when scaling is on
%        scale ticks below exponent=-1,
%        scale ticks above exponent=3,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      major grid style=black,
      axis lines=center,
      ymin=0, ymax=0.202,
      xmin=0, xmax=5.1,
      xtick={0,1,...,5.1},
      width=\linewidth,
      height=10cm,
      xlabel={$F_z(N)$},
      ylabel={$\Delta l(m)$},
      x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/precision=1,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
      },
      y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/precision=3,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
      },
      every axis x label/.style={
        at={(current axis.right of origin)},
        anchor=west,
      },
      every axis y label/.style={
        at={(current axis.north west)},
        anchor=south,
      },
      minor xtick={0,0.1,...,5},
      minor ytick={0,0.002,...,0.2},
      grid=both,
    ]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      major grid style=black,
      axis lines=center,
      ymin=0,
      ymax=25,
      xmin=0, xmax=0.07,
      x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/fixed,
        /pgf/number format/precision=2,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
      },
      ytick={0,5,...,25},
      tick label style={font=\small},
      width=\linewidth,
      height=9cm,
      xlabel={\small $m$ (kg)},
      ylabel={\small $Q$ (kJ)},
      %ticks=both,
      %minor xtick={0,5,...,40},
      minor ytick={0,1,...,25},
      grid=both,
      ylabel near ticks,
      xlabel near ticks,
    ]
    \addplot[very thick, domain=0:1,no markers,samples=3] {250*x};
    \addplot[color=black,fill=black, mark=*,only marks] coordinates{(0.005,3)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]